# Inserting a new object into nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested, insert-update

I have a document in mongodb as follows:

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "name" : "Christine Franklin",
   "degrees" : [
      {
         "level" : "Master",
         info:[ {"major" : "Biology",
         "completion_year" : 2010,
         "faculty" : "Science"}]
      },
    {
         "level" : "Bachelor",
         info : [{"major" : "Biology",
         "completion_year" : 2008,
         "faculty" : "Science"}]
      }
]

}
```

I want to add a new_object(mentioned below) into array "info" only if the "level" is "Bachelor". How to write the query in node.js ?

```
new_object = {"major" : "chemistry",
         "completion_year" : 2010,
         "faculty" : "Science"}
```

The final document should look like this:

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "name" : "Christine Franklin",
   "degrees" : [
      {
         "level" : "Master",
         info:[ {"major" : "Biology",
         "completion_year" : 2010,
         "faculty" : "Science"}]
      },
    {
         "level" : "Bachelor",
         info : [{"major" : "Biology",
         "completion_year" : 2008,
         "faculty" : "Science"},{"major" : "chemistry",
         "completion_year" : 2010,
         "faculty" : "Science"}]
      }
]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $push operator in the update method with the arrayFilters option

```
db.test.update(
  { _id: 1 },
  { $push : { "degrees.$[degree].info" : 
      {
          "major" : "chemistry",
          "completion_year" : 2010,
          "faculty" : "Science"
      } 
  }},
{ arrayFilters : [ {"degree.level" : { $eq: "Bachelor" } } ], multi : true }
```

)

[The filtered positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

[The $push operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

Comment: Yes, "degree" is an identifier of variable. If you open documentation (there is a link - "The filtered positional operator") you will see  { <update operator>: { "<array>.$[<identifier>]" : value } },
   { arrayFilters: [ { <identifier>: <condition> } } ] }. "degrees.$[<identifier>].info" / "<identifier>.level".